# cant compile gst-plaugin-bad-0.10 on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: makefile, gstreamer

I have floowing directory structure for gstraemer sources

```
/home/dev/cerbero/sources/linux_x86_64/gst-plugins-bad-0.10.23
```

when i run .autogen.sh it runs fine

but when i do "make" 
it gives follwing error

[gst-plugins_bad_compile_error](http://pastebin.com/p1J1w7nA)

more specifically

```
Making all in gst
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/dev/cerbero/sources/linux_x86_64/gst-plugins-  bad-0.10.23/gst'
make -C adpcmdec
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/dev/cerbero/sources/linux_x86_64/gst-plugins-bad-0.10.23/gst/adpcmdec'
  CC     libgstadpcmdec_la-adpcmdec.lo
adpcmdec.c:586:21: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '(' token
adpcmdec.c:586:40: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '(' token
adpcmdec.c:586:59: error: unknown type name 'adpcmdec'
adpcmdec.c:587:5: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before string constant
adpcmdec.c:587:22: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'plugin_init'
adpcmdec.c:587:35: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before string constant
adpcmdec.c:587:44: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before string constant
adpcmdec.c:587:52: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before string constant
adpcmdec.c:588:5: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before string constant
adpcmdec.c:576:1: warning: 'plugin_init' defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
make[3]: *** [libgstadpcmdec_la-adpcmdec.lo] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/dev/cerbero/sources/linux_x86_64/gst-plugins-    bad-0.10.23/gst/adpcmdec'
make[2]: *** [adpcmdec] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/dev/cerbero/sources/linux_x86_64/gst-plugins-bad-0.10.23/gst'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/dev/cerbero/sources/linux_x86_64/gst-plugins-bad-0.10.23'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things before building

Did you install liboil and orc compiler?

Run ./configure --enable-orc if you did
Run ./configure if you did not

Then do a make

Remember to do a make distclean before you do the above steps or simply get clean source. Do not do this on the "dirty half built" folder directly.

It could also be a nasm/yasm issue though I doubt it.

EDIT: My suggestin is to install orc because that speeds up gstreamer by a lot!

Comment: ./configure --enable-orc gives error like  "--enable-orc specified, but Orc >= 0.4.11 not found" though i tried to install newest liborc

Comment: are you able to able to invoke orcc from teh command line? Try orcc -h

Comment: but the funny thing is when i assemble a pipeline using gst-launch which includes rtmpsrc as well it runs fine... i think it means  tht bad plugins are installed already but are behaving different.

Comment: I suggest you start with a clean vm with no gstreamer installed and install from scratch.

Comment: Me too think so... but can you tell me which procedure to follow for rtmp i.e " gstreamer plugins bad " to work and to allow me write code using that. As you know there are lots of tutorials regarding it and also which stable version to use ? let me tell you my system configuration , i have 64 bit machine with 4 gb ram and m gonna install ubuntu 12.04 desktop edition . Ill be also installing rtmpd server , suggest me please.

Comment: Use this http://pastebin.com/z96ju3E9 . It is edit of a makefile I use to build various softwares from scratch. See the software versions. If you get an assembly build issue then uninstall nasm and install yasm for that component only. Then revert back to nasm

Comment: can you please tell me which path you mean by TOPDIR in your script ? I tried to search orc but no luck

Comment: Orc: http://code.entropywave.com/orc/   Top dir is just a variable to point to the location where all the src folders are

Comment: I am doing it manually one by one so if i do like                   cd $(code.entropywave.com/orc)/ffmpeg
 ./configure --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-libx264 --enable-shared --enable-libmp3lame
  make -j8
 sudo make install     will it work ?

Comment: Dude that is the path to the orc compiler on web. Go download it from there. I have given you the build commands. Why do you need my folder structure. I said it was and edited makefile so you need to create yours this will not work directly.